# automatic method running on load with singleton javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, singleton

I have a javascript class defined like this:

```
myClass = {
    var1:0,
    var2:0,
    initVars: function() {},
    method1: function() {},
    method2: function() {}
}
```

Now this class is instantly instantiated upon load. ( I believe ) and there is only ever one instance of this class.

Now lets say i want one of the functions, myClass.initVars() to run as soon as the class is ready, is this possible? because at the moment i have this line under where the class is defined

```
myClass.initVars();
```

so as soon as this class has finished being defined, it moves onto the next command.

But is it possible for me to remove this line underneath the class definition and have it run automatically?

Comment: JavaScript does not have "classes". You just define an object. And no, there is no other way. You could call `initVars` immediately and return the object from that method and assign it to `myClass`.

Comment: javascript may not have the class keyword By definition, But i do strongly disagree with the statement that Javascript does not have "classes". The definition of a class is "a class is a construct that is used as a blueprint to create instances of itself" <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)">Source Here</a> And seeing as the Javascript "Objects" fullfill the criteria. I would say that javascript does have "classes". Opinions aside, Thank you for your answer

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could argue about definition. Point taken. But in any case, you are directly creating an object, not a constructor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. Create your object inside an auto-executed function and call the initVars method inside there and then return the newly created and initialised object.

```
myClass = (function(){
   var that = {
      var1:0,
      var2:0,
      initVars: function() {},
      method1: function() {},
      method2: function() {}
   };
   that.initVars();
   return that;
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CQ29F/